# using .htaccess to redirect user based on browser

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect users if they are using Chrome.  I've tried this with javascript/jquery without consistent results, if any. I know how to redirect using .htaccess but not the syntax for redirecting **based on browser**.  Please help!  And if there is a better way, I'm open.

Comment: _“My issue is that when a user is in my php chatroom, the timer does not refresh using jquery .load if accessed from Chrome”_ – well then that’s the issue you should fix.

Comment: Lori please show the current .htaccess redirect code you have. Where would you be redirect them if they are using chrome?

Comment: @CBroe Trust me, I have tried to find that issue and all of the documentation I have found on Chrome regarding this problem says it has been a known issue for a few years and it has not been addressed by Google.  My answer is to forget Chrome, I'm tired of all of it's issues.

Comment: @Panama Jack - Since I want to redirect based on browser, I have no code or I would have implemented it already. That's the problem, I do not know the syntax for redirecting based on browser.

Comment: _“it has been a known issue for a few years and it has not been addressed by Google”_ – and what issue would that be, specifically? Can you refer to any bug reports in that regard …?

Comment: @CBroe - using jquery to load() at intervals does not work in chrome

Comment: That’s not very specific … unless you can show some hard evidence for that claim, I’ll doubt that this is an unsolvable problem.

Comment: I have been trying to find a solution all day to that very problem.  Regardless, I am asking for .htaccess syntax to redirect based on browser.  That's really all I need.

Comment: I'm not going to re-research this entire issue for another 8 hours.  I don't even need to explain why I want .htaccess syntax.  Seriously?  That's all I need.  I don't need anything but .htaccess syntax to redirect user according to browser.  It doesn't really matter why I need it.  I need it.

Answer (score 0):

Redirection

There is a tool in the cPanel that can create the Redirects for you, please see How to create a Redirect

Redirect from a specific file to a new file

Example:

Redirect /redirect_from.html newsite.com/folder/redirect_to.html
In the above example, a file in the root directory called redirect_example.html is redirected to the URL newsite.com/folder/redirect_example.html 
If the old file were in a subdirectory then you could use:

/subdirectory/redirect_from.html
WildCard Redirect / Redirecting from one folder to a new folder

Redirect /redirect_from newsite.com/redirect_to
Now any request to your site below /olddirectory will be redirected to the new site, with the extra information in the URL added on, for example if someone typed in:

http://www.example.com/redirect_from/images/image.gif
They would be redirected to:

http://www.newsite.com/redirect_to/images/image.gif

Comment: Thanks, I do know how to do this.  BUT, I need to redirect based on the user's browser.  Specifically, if Chrome redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Now i got your problem and have a solution too. You can use RewriteCond directive in .htaccess file to test the user's client whether firefox or chrome and redirect accordingly. The code will look something shown below:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Firefox
RewriteRule ^abc.html$ example.com/xy/firefox.html [R=301]

This will redirect all the browsers having firefox in their user string to firefox.html. You need to find how many browsers named their user string and put it in the code accordingly.
Some problem may come when you would not able to find the right HTTP_USER_AGENT string for a browser i.e. if chrome's user name is firefox then also the users of chrome will be redirected to firefox.html.

Hence, the code below might work for you:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Firefox
RewriteRule ^me.html$ firefox.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Chrome
RewriteRule ^me.html$ chrome.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE
RewriteRule ^me.html$ ie.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Safari
RewriteRule ^me.html$ safari.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Opera
RewriteRule ^me.html$ opera.html [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^me.html$ default.html [L]

The L flag makes sure that if no user string matches then the default page opens for it.

I hope this will help you.